# Quickly change the font size in Terminal

Tags: terminal, vi

I'm looking for a way to perhaps type a command and have the font change by increments of say 5 or 10. Right now Cmd-+ is taking too long if I want to go from a small font to a large font. I'm using Neovim through Terminal. Is there a way to do this? Vim plugins don't seem to work. Perhaps a terminal emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Why not open terminal preferences and choose to change the defaults. You can then open a new tab at the exact size and color you prefer?

That and using `screen` or `tmux` means you can have your environment run regardless of which window you place it in. The zoom increments are better for temporary small adjustments as you so correctly have pointed out.